# Are redirects bad UX?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, redirect

I have a client that wants to redirect all direct traffic from their campaign site's homepage to a new interactive feature we've built for the campaign.

For social, I think this is less of a concern (since you're redirected from social anyway) but am slightly worried that for people that enter through search or type in the URL (highly unlikely) it could be a jarring experience to see the URL redirect. I've reached out to my team to see where traffic to the campaign is coming from, but don't have that data yet.

I'm leaning toward a redirect being fine, and that I'm probably overreacting, but wanted to gut check just in case.

Comment: redirection from "gmail.com" or bit.ly links to the actual sites never bothered me... though redirection from americanexpress.com to centresuite.co.uk is more troublesome (yes, they actually use the latter domain in some countries) => it depends on the application

Comment: Goto: http://www.google.com/gmail (go old school - type it in).

How "jarred" do you feel?

It changed. Did you notice? Probably not. Were you even looking at the URL bar after you hit `enter`? Probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Depends on where you're being redirected to.**

Is it a new version of your website that no longer contains pageUrl the user entered? **Nope then - it's useful to redirect**. Just use a message conveying that the URL does not exist and you're redirecting them to the homepage in a few seconds.

Is it a **completely different website** than the one you wish to open? 
**Yes**, it will be a bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm aware of an unexpected redirect when trying to go to a site's homepage, I tend to be suspicious and will often close the browser. Depending on users' settings, some browsers will warn of the redirect but if the page is on the same domain it shouldn't cause that to happen.

If the new interactive page requires users to sign up prior to seeing the rest of the site content, don't do it. In my opinion, nothing is more off-putting than a site requiring me to sign up before I have a chance to evaluate the site's purpose or content.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely its a bad UX. Best way to handle this case is put permission before redirecting. Us pop up with asking permission about the redirect. It generates faith in the user's mind

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a bad UX as long as people are landing on the expected website.

In your case the client is expecting you to redirect users from old campaigning site to a new interactive site for campaigning. **As long as the look & feel and content matches with an feedback message that read: "Welcome to our new interactive website".** Majority of the users will be delighted to see the newer version, and since you mentioned it is an interactive feature - it will keep the users engaged.